# git list of files changed between two tags along with intermediate tags changes

Tags: git

I am trying to get the list of files that are changed between two git tags. These tags has some other tags as well.

```
git diff tags/v1.0.0 tags/v1.5.0 --name-only
```

The above command displays the diff between those tags (changes in v1.5.0 only) and don't include the intermediate tag changes. I have also tried

```
git rev-list tags/v1.5.0 ^tags/v1.0.0 --count
```

This will give me the count of commits between these two tags. And then

```
git diff tags/v1.5.0~count tags/v1.5.0 --name-only
```

But this is giving me incorrect data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by list of files between tags? Are you wanting only changed files? What is the result so far? What do you expect instead?

Comment: I want to get the list of files that are changed between the tags. if there are 5 files changed in each version from v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1,20...v1.5.0, I want to see the name of 25 files that got changed. Instead I am getting only the 5 files changed as part of v1.5.0 @e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> git rev-list tags/v1.5.0 ^tags/v1.0.0 --count
> ```
>
> This will give me the count of commits between these two tags.

No, it will give you the count of commits *reachable from* `tags/v1.5.0` that are *not reachable from* `tags/v1.0.0`.

To illustrate the difference, suppose we have a graph fragment like this:

```
          *--*--*      *   <-- tags/v1.5.0
         /       \    /
...--o--o---------*--*--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--o   <-- tags/v1.0.0
```

Here, release `v1.0.0` was created at about the same time as the feature bubble along the top, but then there were a few fixes needed.  Later, the feature was merged into master and since then release `v1.5.0` was created and needed one commit to fix it up as well.  (Meanwhile `master` has continued to accumulate work.)

The commits that are marked with a star `*` are *reachable from* the label `tags/v1.5.0`, by starting at the commit to which the label points and working backwards, following all paths (including the feature bubble).

In this case, there are six such commits.

> ```
> git diff tags/v1.5.0~count tags/v1.5.0 --name-only
> ```

The `~` operator is a graph-following operator.  It moves back some number of *first parent* steps.  The first parent of the `1.5.0` commit is on `master`, the second parent is a *merge* commit on `master`, and the third parent is the main-line-row `*`.  The fourth parent is the `o` that has the fork that leads to `tags/v1.0.0`, the fifth is a commit that is reachable from all names, and the sixth commit back along that first-parent axis comes before the part of the graph shown here.

Because your actual issue is not well-defined, it is hard to say what the correct approach might be.  You might look for the merge base(s) between the two tags, then use `--ancestry-path` to select commits that are descendants of this merge base but ancestors of the second tag, and check to see whether any of those commits are reachable from other tags and if so what merge base(s) fall along the ancestry-path line.  Note that the direct ancestry path from `tags/v1.0.0` to `tags/v1.5.0` is empty since `tags/v1.0.0` is not an ancestor of any of the starred commits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it clear. My usecase is to get the list of files changed between two commits which should include the intermediate commit changes as well.

Comment: You still haven't addressed what you mean by "between". Consider the graph drawing above (remember that commit linkages are always backwards, i.e., right-to-left in the diagram). Which commits are "between" the two commits tagged with labels? There's no path leading from the earlier tag to the later tag, because "forward" means "rightward" and there's nothing *after* `v1.0.0`.